# Why would I get a 404 on "Authoring Information" autocomplete?

Tags: ajax

Below is a screenshot of a 404 I'm receiving on the standard author autocomplete, and I can't figure out, for the life of me, why this would be happening.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely because your autocomplete isn't actually using the standard path for the user autocomplete.

From the image, your autocomplete is pointing to `/login/autocomplete`, a path that doesn't exist in a standard Drupal installation (or indeed one with about 200 contrib modules enabled, I just grepped a couple of large projects).

The correct path for the user autocomplete is `/user/autocomplete`.

Presumably there's some custom/contrib code changing the autocomplete to a different path, but failing to actually implement that path.

The best thing to do would be to search your codebase for the string `login/autocomplete` and go from there.

**UPDATE**

The change might be being made by the User Tweaks module:

```
function user_tweaks_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if (user_access('view login autocomplete')) {
    switch ($form_id) {
      case 'user_login_block':
      case 'user_login':
      case 'user_pass':
        $form['name']['#autocomplete_path'] = 'user/login/autocomplete';
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Clive, perfect!  I had created an alias for **user/login** at **login**, and this was causing the conflict.

Comment: Oops, I meant to say an alias for **user** at **login**